# How to get the progress value of seekbar, which was BEFORE the actual progress value?

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I have a question, How to get the progress value of seekbar, which was BEFORE the actual progress value? How can I do this here is a code which gets tehe actual value of progress on seekbar:

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new 

OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p=progress;
    }
});
```

This part of code is pretty popular when you are using a seekbar. But I couldn t find any solution how you can get the `int progress` which was before of the `int progress`. So I m loking for something like: `int progressbefore`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Than try  to get progress  inside [**`onStartTrackingTouch`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener#onStartTrackingTouch(android.widget.SeekBar))

Comment: I know what you mean, but it s the first value. I want to update this value you like int `actual progress` - 1 so the direct progress before.

Comment: where will you use that variable? inside the callback methods or somewhere else?

Comment: Create the private variable to save previous value of the progress

Comment: @Nikos Hidalgo I m going to use this variable in onProgressChanged.

Comment: @Alexander Chermin Can zou show me how to do this or explainor just send me a little piece of code.

Comment: @psuch have created the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable `progressBefore` at the class level:

```
private int progressBefore = 0;
```

and these methods:

```
private int getProgressBefore() {
    return progressBefore;
}

private void setProgressBefore(int p) {
    progressBefore = p;
}
```

and inside `onProgressChanged()` check it every time you want to do something and at the end assign to it the new `progress`:

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        int p = getProgressBefore();
        // do something
        setProgressBefore(progress);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new 

OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
private int prevousProgressValue = 0;
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prevoiusProgresValue = seekBar.getProgress(); //start value;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO something with current

    previousProgresValue = progress;
}
});
```